# I need to create a mysql query to find specifik comments

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and i need to do the following:

```
select comment_post_ID,comment_content, COUNT(comment_post_ID) from wpvo_comments where comment_content like "Dintero Order created with%" GROUP BY comment_post_ID HAVING COUNT(comment_post_ID)>1 ORDER BY `wpvo_comments`.`comment_post_ID` DESC;
```

This code works as expected, it finds duplicates of the phrase "Dinteor order created". However I need to do an additional check and that is to check if the same comment_post_id->comment_content also contains "The Dintero order%"

I have tried this:

```
select comment_post_ID,comment_content, COUNT(comment_post_ID) from wpvo_comments where comment_content like "Dintero Order created with%" AND comment_content LIKE "The Dintero order%" GROUP BY comment_post_ID HAVING COUNT(comment_post_ID)>1 ORDER BY `wpvo_comments`.`comment_post_ID` DESC;
```

But it doesnt work.

I have posted an image of and example and it shows multiple "Dintero order created" and also the second phrase. I would like to get all post_IDs that contain both "The Dintero Order" and "Dintero Order created with" (but only if "Dintero Order created with" appeared more than 1 time)

Here is an image of how the table/row looks
[Example how the table is looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf06s.png)
I hope you understand what Iam trying to do...

```
select comment_post_ID,comment_content, COUNT(comment_post_ID) from wpvo_comments where comment_content like "Dintero Order created with%" GROUP BY comment_post_ID HAVING COUNT(comment_post_ID)>1 ORDER BY `wpvo_comments`.`comment_post_ID` DESC;
```

did not do what i needed, only half of it.

Comment: "it doesnt work" - what does that mean? Are you facing any error message?

Comment: Also, how could the same text start with `Dinteor order` **and** `The Dintero order`? I couldn't imaging any case where this is possible?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, Look at the image, there is one row in comment_content starting with "Dintero Order created with reference....." and then with the same comment_post_ID there is another row starting with "The dintero order has been captured".  My problem is that some orders are getting duplicate "Dintero order created with reference" and some of these orders dont have the "Dinter order has been captured" and so the order is corrupt and I need to fix it manually. 

However, since I have no idea how many orders I need to find which orders.

Comment: With my first code, I can get all orders with duplicate "Dintero order created with reference" but i need to narrow it down to the ones having the second row as well (Dintero order has been captured)

Comment: I have almost figured it out.

Comment: SELECT comment_post_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM (
   SELECT comment_post_ID
   FROM wpvo_comments
   WHERE comment_content LIKE "Dintero Order created with%"
   GROUP BY comment_post_ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
) a
JOIN (
   SELECT comment_post_ID
   FROM wpvo_comments
   WHERE comment_content like "The dintero order %"
   GROUP BY comment_post_ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
) b ON a.comment_post_ID = b.comment_post_ID
GROUP BY comment_post_ID
ORDER BY comment_post_ID DESC;

Comment: but I get: comment_post_ID' i field list is not unique

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, if you are facing a new error message, what have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Also, why do you try to join these two result selts? Why not use a `OR` between the two `LIKE` parts if you want to have all rows where either the one or the other is matching?